# How to store value from foreach parallel Powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I am a powershell beginner and I just want to know what would be the best way to store all the value of my $allusers variable into one object? I am running the command inside the foreach parallel and I cant store all of the data into my global variable. Thank you so much in advance for someone who already faced this issue.

```
Function Get-Members {
    param ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$FileName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$searchFileURL
    )
  
    $storageHolder = @()
    
    $groupList = Get-Content $searchFileURL  #| ForEach-Object { $_ }
    $groupList |  ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        
       
        Import-Module -Name "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Get-ADUserMembers.psm1" 
        $allusers = Get-ADUserMembers -GroupName $_ | Select-Object ParentGroup, Name, EmployeeNumber, Enabled, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet
        


        $storageHolder +=  $allusers <------------ This is not working even the $Using:storageHolder

       
    } 
 


}
```

Comment: Hi, does `Get-ADUserMembers` actually work for you? I don't recognize that cmdlet from the AD Module i have loaded on my system.

Comment: Hello, I made that function and put in module by myself to get all users from nested groups. Now my problem is on how to store it all outside the parallel because I want it to make an output in csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply output the data from the `ForEach-Object` block and assign to a variable that will collect all outputs, as showcased by [example 12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1#example-12--retrieve-log-entries-in-parallel).

```
$storageHolder = $groupList | ForEach-Object -Parallel {     
   
    Import-Module -Name "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Get-ADUserMembers.psm1" 
    Get-ADUserMembers -GroupName $_ | Select-Object ParentGroup, Name, EmployeeNumber, Enabled, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet       
}
```

PowerShell will automatically create and expand an array, if there are multiple objects output from the `ForEach-Object` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much zett42! 

I did this parallel way because I though that this would make my process faster. But my normal foreach is more faster than this way? May I ask for your input about that?

Comment: @DennisDemandaco I suggest to post a new question.